# Restore of database fails

Tags: sql-server, ssms, restore

I got the error message below while restoring the database from the shared folder.

> Restore of database failed 'XYZ'. Modify file encountered operating system error 112 there is not enough space on the disk while attempting to expand the physical file.

The backup file size is 28 GB. Restore is to the H: drive having 500 GB of free space. How do I solve this?

Comment: It may be due to the shared drive space constraint to you. Have you checked with the local drive where the database you want to restore?

Comment: Restoring a mssql database involves two files (or more) - a data file and a log file.  Sounds like the data file (.mdf) may be pointing to the H: drive, but it is possible that the log file (.ldf) may be pointing to C: or another drive.  Check Options when you restore and check the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to get the file size of the backup and then you can check whether or not your drives have enough space available:

```
restore filelistonly FROM DISK='drive:\path\backup_file.bak'
```